# API Gateway POST request returns "error http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin”

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

So I'm trying to write a POST method that triggers a lambda function which will in turn write to a DynamoDB database. The logic behind all of that seems fine, and I can invoke the lambda function when I make a POST request to the API through POSTMAN. However, when I try to do the same from my actual application, which doesn't currently have a domain, I get the error:

> Type error: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Since I don't have a domain I am developing using localhost:3000. Can I get this to work with API Gateway? I already have CORS setup with [*] as my list of domains, so this should be open to every domain.

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on your API Gateway Resource? There's a checkbox you can use to enable it easily.

Comment: Yes CORS is enabled. I'm wondering if it's an issue with using localhost:3000 as my origin. Like I said it works through Postman

Answer (score 0):

Try to

change localhost to "lvh.me" which points to 127.0.0.1

or

edit your hosts file so that local.[mysite].com points to 127.0.0.1, then make your CORS file allow *.[mysite].com

check: 
[stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)